# Send Json object and file to controller with Javascript in MVC

Tags: javascript, json, file, asp.net-mvc-4, send

I have a Json object like :

```
  var appversion = { "Id": "", "Version": "", "HelpSystemId": "", "Content": "", "FileName": "", "IsLatest": "", "LastModify": "", "AppVersionChangsets": [] };
        appversion.Id = $("#Id").val();
        appversion.Version = $("#Version").val();
        appversion.HelpSystemId = $("#HelpSystemId").val();
        appversion.IsLatest = $("#IsLatest").val();
        appversion.LastModify = $("#LastModify").val();
```

and a file that I get it this way in my form :

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.MyLabelFor(model => model.Content, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" id="_file" name="_file" />
            <button onclick="abortRead();">Cancel read</button>
            <div id="progress_bar"><div class="percent">0%</div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and I send it to my controller :

```
 $.ajax({
          url: '/AppVersion/Create2',
          data: JSON.stringify(appversion),
          type: 'POST',
          contentType: 'application/json;',
          dataType: 'json',
         success: function (result) {
               if (result.Success == "1") {
                    window.location.href = "/AppVersion/index";
               }
               else {
                   alert(result.ex);
               }
           }});
```

controller is :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public JsonResult Create2(AppVersion appversion)
    {
    //Some Code
    }
```

my problem is I can not access to my file in controller . I just get my json object .how can I send file with Json Object to Controller ?

```
  if (Request.Files["file"].ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    Stream str = Request.Files["file"].InputStream;
                    byte[] data = new byte[str.Length];
                    str.Read(data, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(str.Length));
                }
```

Comment: do you put authentication `@Controller` at your controller?

Comment: No yet . no authentication set for my controller

Comment: try to put the `@Controller` at your controller and make sure your controller is executing.

Comment: how can I send file with Json Object to Controller, you mean how to post json object to controller or what?

Comment: can you send me a link of an example ?

Comment: @MDDDC No . I have a Json object with name : 'AppVersion'  and a file that I want to upload it to controller .

Answer (score 0):

There is a Jquery plugin called 'ajaxfileupload', maybe U can use it.
The url is 'http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/'.

Comment: I search for upload file with js and find many answer like this . thay work great . but I want to send json object and file together . if I send one of them it work but I want both